# Spring Web Flow + Apache Tiles + Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-webflow, apache-tiles

I want to integrate Ajax and Apache Tiles with Spring Web Fow. Simple flow without Tiles is working fine, but it is throwing `NullPointerException` after integrating with Tiles.
Here is the Web Flow servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd">




    <bean id="transportWebFlow" class="com.demo.controller.DemoController"/>

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
            <!-- <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.FlowAjaxTilesView"/>
    </bean> -->

     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/tilesDefination/demo.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
      </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>/*.html=flowController</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    </webflow:flow-executor>


    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows/" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location id="demo" path="demo-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>


    <webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"
    view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" development="true"/>


     <bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property name="viewResolvers" ref ="tilesViewResolver"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Tiles Configuration for webflow**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" 
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
    <tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.demo" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/demoLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Travel.com"/>
    <put-attribute name="demoHeader" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/demoHeader.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="demoBody" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="demoFooter" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/demoFooter.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="demo" extends="base.demo">
        <put-attribute name="demoBody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/demo.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    </tiles-definitions>
```

**demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">


<var name="demo" class="com.demo.model.Demo"/>
<view-state id="demo" view="/WEB-INF/jsp/demo.jsp" model="demo">
</view-state>
</flow>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.demo.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.demo.model.Demo;

@Controller
public class DemoController {


    @RequestMapping(value="demo.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView demo(){
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        return new ModelAndView("demo","demo", demo);
    }
}
```

This is the exception stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringFlow] in context with path [/DemoWebFlow] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'demo' of flow 'demo'] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```